# How to create two separate apps in the same solution

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have an application APP1 that must share a lot of code with another application APP0.
Both application share all project dependency and the only thing that is different is the  build configuration. I would therefore like to manage both of them in the same solution file.

I need also to be able to deploy both apps to the store.

Here's what i did:

1) Copy/Paste of APP0.csproj and renamed to APP1.csproj

2) Add APP1 to solution

3) Copy/Paste of APP0.appxmanifest and renamed to APP1.appxmanifest

4) Copy/Paste of APP0.StoreAssociation.xml and renamed to APP0.StoreAssociation.xml

5) Added APP1 files to APP1 project and APP0 files to APP0 project

I also checked that APP1.csproj was given a new guid.
The problem remains: when i debug APP0, APP1 is removed from the dashboard. When i debug APP1, APP0 is removed. So there is something that still makes both apps look like the same...
Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Deploying seems to work fine, so right click on APP1 or APP0 and pressing Deploy actually provides 2 separate apps in the dashboard.

Comment: You're probably going to have to have two solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you did everything right to make sure that you can build both projects, but if you want to have an option to install them separately you need to make sure that you will specify unique identities for these two projects. Check the [Package identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464929.aspx#package_identity) page.

For example you can change the Package Name of one of the projects in appxmanifest file (last tab "Packaging" -> Change the "Package Name").